# VBA Copy & Paste only selecting 2 cells based on active sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting a strange error with my code whereby if I don't have the sheet SOH active before running the macro it will only copy cells B1 & B2 into my other workbook Template Build.

I've attached my workings below.

```
Public Sub Info_Copy()
   Dim Lastrow As Integer
   Dim SOH As Excel.Workbook
   Set SOH = Workbooks("StockOH")
   Dim Template As Excel.Workbook
   Set Template = Workbooks("Template Build")

Lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


SOH.Sheets("NSF").Activate
Range("B2:B" & Lastrow).Copy
Template.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Which is the last used row in column A of the sheet that is active when you invoke the macro?  That will dictate what `Lastrow` is set to.  (If the active sheet was blank, it will be set to 1, which means you are copying "B2:B1".)

Comment: You're counting rows in the Activesheet before activating the sheet ("StockOH") that has the data.

Comment: @Winterknell, according to the code, `StockOH` is a `Workbook` not a `Worksheet`. If that's the case then OP has a workbook object called `SOH` and a sheet called `SOH`. No wonder OP is confused.

Comment: Oops, you're right. My bad. Still, the advice stands: OP is counting rows in the wrong sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are counting the number of rows on the *active sheet* because you used the `ActiveSheet` object.

If you don't want to use the active sheet each time you need to tell it *exactly* which sheet to use. For example:

```
Lastrow = Workbooks("SomeWorkbook").Worksheets("SomeSheet").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

It's difficult to tell, but my guess is you need something like this

```
Lastrow = SOH.Worksheets("SOH").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: since you're working between different workbooks you want to qualify `Rows.Count` up to wanted workbook worksheet, like for instance `Lastrow = SOH.Worksheets("SOH").Cells(SOH.Worksheets("SOH").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Answer (score 2):

I guess you'r after something like this:

```
Public Sub Info_Copy()
    Dim SOH As Excel.Workbook
    Set SOH = Workbooks("StockOH")
    Dim Template As Excel.Workbook
    Set Template = Workbooks("Template Build")

    With SOH.Sheets("NSF") '<--| reference wanted sheet in wanted workbook
        .Range("B2:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Copy Destination:=Template.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2") '<--| copy its column "B" cells from row 2 down to column A last not empty row and paste it to 'Template' workbook "Sheet1" worksheet from cell B2"
    End With
End Sub
```

when working between different workbooks it's important you qualify range references up to `workbook` object because:

- different excel version workbooks may have different sheet rows number, so that `.Rows.Count` must be referenced to the correct workbook
- different workbooks can have worksheets with the same name